# why it doesn't display "you had wrong" message?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Often i use ajax by jquery but according to the below code why it doesn't display "you had wrong" message when "IF"is true?  and just display "faile" message?

file Login.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
<title>just for test</title>
</head>
<div id="Response" ></div>
<h3>login</h3>
<form id="Login" class="form-login">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="yourname" id="yourname" placeholder="yourname">
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-bricky pull-left"> ورود <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> </button>
</form>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>
$(document).ready(function (e){
$("#Login").on('submit',(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "include/php/check_login.php",
        type: "POST",
        data:  new FormData(this),
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        success: function(data)
        {
            if(data=='faile'){
             $("#Response").html('you had wrong...');
            }else{
             $("#Response").html(data);
            }
              return false;
            }       
        });
}));
});        
    </script>
</body><!-- end: BODY -->
</html>
```

file:check_login.php

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['yourname']) && !empty($_POST['yourname']))
{
    $yourname=$_POST['yourname']; 
    echo $yourname;
}
else echo "faile";
?>
```

Comment: I just copied and pasted the code in my IDE... it works well as you require it. Bye the way you can use json based method..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is method for receiving json based data

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js"> <head> <title>just for test</title> </head>

    <body>

        <div id="Response" ></div>

        <h3>login</h3>
        <form id="Login" class="form-login">
             <input type="text" class="form-control" name="yourname" id="yourname" placeholder="yourname">
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-bricky pull-left"> ورود <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> </button>
        </form>

        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(function (e) {

                $("#Login").submit(function(e){

                e.preventDefault();

                $.ajax({

                    url: "check_login.php",
                    data:  new FormData(this),

                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: false,
                    cache: false,
                    processData:false,

                    // data type should be set to json to get the response data as json value
                    dataType: 'json',

                    success: function(json) {

                            if( json.data == 'faile') {

                                $("#Response").html('you had wrong...');

                            } else {

                                $("#Response").html(json.data);

                            }

                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                });
            });

        </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

**check_login.php**

```
<?php

    session_start();
    if (isset($_POST['yourname']) && !empty($_POST['yourname']))
    {
        $response = array( "data" => $_POST['yourname']);

    } else {$response = array( "data" => "faile");}

    echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

Using json, there should be no error regarding `\n` :: the new line after echo

Answer (score 0):

Place

```
var yourname=$('#yourname').val();
```

between `<script>` and `$(document).ready(function (e){`

and change from

```
data:  new FormData(this),
```

to

```
data: "yourname="+yourname;
```

Answer (score 0):

Look for newline that is returned after the `?>`, as it returns something like `"faile\n"`.

You can use one of:

- remove the closing `?>` tag
- add `die` after `echo`
- check for `"faile\n"`(not recommended)

Comment: Or trim leading/trailing white space on the client side before testing the value.

Answer (score 0):

add `die();` after `else echo "faile";`